# User react router inside of map

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to use `react-router` (must use 2.8.1) for rendering content inside a list (using `map`).

However, if I display `{this.props.children}` outside the `.map`, it renders one at time.

I need it to display inline/under the list entry.

How can I achieve this?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: x.movies
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Repos</h2>
        {x.movies.map(movie =>
          <span key={movie.id}>
            {movie.name}
            <NavLink to={"/repos/" + movie.id + "/next"}>React Router</NavLink>
          </span>
        )}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the `children` inside the loop, which i believe is causing the extra `Next Id:4` to be displayed between each entry.

Try the below, by rendering the children outside the loop.

```
{
  x.movies.map(movie => (
        <span>
        <Result key={movie.id} result= {movie}/>
        </span>
      ))
}
<span>{this.props.children}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is no different from my example. It renders `next ID:4` under the map. It should render the `next ID:4` under the item it belongs to